# iOS Notification for alarm

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am making a timer app. The user sets the amount of hours, minutes, and seconds they want it to count down. How can I make it display a banner notification for when they are not in the app when the timer runs out?

I can get the countdown time in seconds if that is needed. I just want it to display like any other notification; for example, the messages app puts notifications on the lockscreen when the phone is off, put them on top of other apps, and puts them in notification centre.

If it is also possible, could I have it so that the user can turn off the alarm without having to go back into the app?

Thank you!

Comment: Why dont you post some of your code,  what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Just set a Local Notification while app goes to background in the AppDelegete file. Set the remaining time in the code below.

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UILocalNotification *locNot = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSTimeInterval interval; // Your Alarms Remaining time in seconds
    locNot.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: locNot];
}
```